# PHP counter doesn't work

Tags: php, counter

I created a short code, where the counter is used to count up the elements, but the counter counts only till "1", why?

```
<?php $counter = "0";?>
<?php foreach($this->group('inhalt') as $i => $fields): ?>
    <?php $counter += 1 ;?>
    <div class="ce_countup autogrid-id_<?php echo $this->id; ?>_<?php echo $counter;?> autogrid-type_cte <?php if($counter ="1"){ echo "autogrid-first";} ?> <?php if($counter =$gridKlasse){ echo "autogrid-last";} ?> <?php echo $gridKlasse;?> autogrid_mode_auto autogrid block">
        <h3 id="ce_id_<?php echo $this->id; ?>_<?php echo $counter;?>"><?php echo $this->field('zahl#'.$i)->value(); ?></h3>
        <?php echo $this->field('bezeichnung#'.$i)->value(); ?>
    </div>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
<?php if($counter ="1"){ echo "autogrid-first";} ?>
```

and here

```
<?php if($counter = $gridKlasse){ echo "autogrid-last";} ?>
```

You're always re-initializing the `$counter` variable with 1 and then doing a boolean evaluation of the whole expression. You should use either `==` or `===` to fix the problem. Also, `$gridKlasse` should be a number.

Try this:

```
<?php $counter = 0;?>
    <?php foreach($this->group('inhalt') as $i => $fields): ?>
    <?php $counter += 1 ;?>
    <div class="ce_countup autogrid-id_<?php echo $this->id; ?>_<?php echo $counter;?> autogrid-type_cte <?php if($counter === 1){ echo "autogrid-first";} ?> <?php if($counter === $gridKlasse){ echo "autogrid-last";} ?> <?php echo $gridKlasse;?> autogrid_mode_auto autogrid block">
        <h3 id="ce_id_<?php echo $this->id; ?>_<?php echo $counter;?>"><?php echo $this->field('zahl#'.$i)->value(); ?></h3>
        <?php echo $this->field('bezeichnung#'.$i)->value(); ?>
    </div>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```